# Ubuntu 20.04 loses connexion after sometime

Tags: networking, server, ssh, docker

I hope I will find any help here.

I have a server running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64bit fresh. Everything is working fine.
I installed there only docker where I run another ubuntu container which is quite heavy like 40Go.

I can run this ubuntu container and everything inside.

But suddenly, I get thrown out of server when using ssh and from that point of time, nothing works. I can neither access the port 80 on the browser nor reconnect with ssh.

I always need to hard reboot the server.

I took a look at the journal log and I saw the following:

```
Aug 31 10:51:17 myserverXXX systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
Aug 31 10:51:17 myserverXXX systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Aug 31 10:51:17 myserverXXX systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
Aug 31 10:51:17 myserverXXX systemd-journald[27]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
Aug 31 10:51:17 myserverXXX systemd-logind[918]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Power Button)
Aug 31 10:51:17 myserverXXX systemd-logind[918]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Sleep Button)
Aug 31 10:51:17 myserverXXX systemd-logind[918]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX systemd-logind[918]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event3 (HID 0557:2419)
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX systemd-networkd[586]: vethf4b126a: Gained IPv6LL
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX systemd-journald[27]: File /var/log/journal/4e719740d1fa86abf29ff1e361223c8a/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX audit[162669]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=162669 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX audit[162669]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=162669 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX audit[162668]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=162668 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX audit[162670]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=162670 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX audit[162670]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=162670 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX audit[162670]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=162670 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1630403478.827:59): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=162669 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1630403478.827:60): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=162669 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1630403478.827:61): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=162668 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1630403478.827:62): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=162670 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1630403478.827:63): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=162670 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:18 myserverXXX kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1630403478.827:64): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=162670 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 31 10:51:19 myserverXXX kernel: proc: Bad value for 'hidepid'
Aug 31 10:51:19 myserverXXX kernel: proc: Bad value for 'hidepid'
Aug 31 10:51:19 myserverXXX kernel: proc: Bad value for 'hidepid'
Aug 31 10:51:19 myserverXXX kernel: proc: Bad value for 'hidepid'
Aug 31 10:51:22 myserverXXX kernel: proc: Bad value for 'hidepid'
Aug 31 10:51:23 myserverXXX kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
Aug 31 11:11:23 myserverXXX kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
```

Where myserverXXX stands for my server domain.

Please, can someone help me? I'm struggling on this problem since almost one week.

```
Aug 31 17:32:07 775fcd1e77c8 ModemManager[137]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Aug 31 17:32:07 775fcd1e77c8 NetworkManager[103]: <info>  [1630423927.0678] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug 31 17:32:07 775fcd1e77c8 NetworkManager[103]: <info>  [1630423927.0679] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 31 17:32:07 775fcd1e77c8 gnome-shell[558]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Aug 31 17:32:07 775fcd1e77c8 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 31 17:32:07 775fcd1e77c8 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 31 17:32:07 775fcd1e77c8 systemd-sleep[7303]: Suspending system...
Aug 31 17:32:07 775fcd1e77c8 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu Desktop 20.04? Or Ubuntu Server 20.04?

Comment: It is Ubuntu server precisely Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-81-generic x86_64).

Comment: Hmmmm. The log entry `PM: suspend entry (s2idle)` suggests that Power Management is enabled. That's very unusual for Ubuntu Server: It's enabled on Ubuntu Desktop and disabled on Ubuntu Server. Have you any idea what you did to enable it? Alternately, perhaps you actually installed Ubuntu Desktop and are merely using it as a server?